# Why my tag anchor does not work at localhost using Ratchet framework?

Tags: html

I'm using the Ratchet framework to compose a web page, but any anchor tags doest work, even though I am using the true rule, for example:

```
<a class="control-item" href="contact.php">click me</a>
```

The above code does not work. I really don't understand, but works with pure HTML code, and other frameworks.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I really don't understand what "don't Works" means, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

An anchor won't work for the following reasons:

- The link isn't linked to a page that exists.
- The link is linked to a page that uses a server side language and
  you're running locally and not through a server.
- The link doesn't have an appropriate opening/closing tag.

It should seem that you're most likely not running through a server (or your server is not running correctly). Please define what "not working" means.